# Counting number of arrangements with beads

Tags: combinatorics

My friend lost 2 charms off her 7-charm bracelet. For her birthday, I bought her a new charm to replace one of the lost ones. Unfortunately, I messed up and got her a duplicate of one of the charms she still has. How many distinguishable ways can she put her 6 charms on her bracelet? (Two of the charms are the same, rotations are indistinguishable, and turning the bracelet front-to-back is indistinguishable.)

Here is how I tried to solve this problem.
Total number of charms in the bracelet is now 6 with 2 duplicates. If all charms were distinct then we would have 5!/2 arrangements. With duplicate charms I think I should divide it by 2. So my answer is 30. Am I wrong?
I need to teach this to a sixth grader. So any input about how to best explain is appreciated. Any website where I can read up more...
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is correct, and  I will try to explain why, in as simple a manner shortly.

Firstly, consider seating **6** people in a circle. There is no fixed reference point, (as for  seating in a row) so one person is "lost" in creating a reference point, and thus # of arrangements = **5!**

Now a bracelet with distinct charms (unlike seats in a circle) can be flipped, which means that an arrangement viewed clockwise becomes anti-clockwise on flipping, thus a further division by 2 is needed, and the # of arrangements becomes **5!/2.**

Finally, to come to our particular bracelet, create the reference point using one of the **distinct** charms. We now need arrangements of **3** distinct and **2** identical charms, which is **5!/2!** by the formula for permutations with repetitions, and further divide by 2 because it can be flipped.

In general, # of arrangements for seating of n people in a circle is **(n-1)!** against **n!** for seating in a row, and for flippable bracelets, becomes **$\dfrac{(n-1)!}{2}$**,

Comment: You can see the "examples" portion at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29, although the explanations may need to be adapted for sixth graders.